# When i try to run this code output is "merge.exe has stopped working"?

Tags: c++, arrays, mergesort

```
#include<iostream>
#define INF 10000
using namespace std;
void mergeSort(int *x,int y,int z);
void merge(int *a,int p,int q,int r);
void main()
{
int i,size;
cin>>size;
int arr[size];
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    cin>>arr[i];
} 
mergeSort(arr,0,size-1);
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
}
}
```

> This function takes in the array to be sorted and the values of starting and ending index i.e, y,z.

```
void mergeSort(int *x,int y,int z)
{
int q;
if(y<z)
{
    q=(y+z)/2;
    mergeSort(x,y,q);
    mergeSort(x,q+1,z);
    merge(x,y,q,z);
}
}
```

> this function merges two sorted sections of the array and p,r are starting and ending index while q is the index which divides the array into two sorted parts

```
void merge(int *a,int p,int q,int r)
{
int l1,l2,i,j;
l1=q-p+1;
l2=r-q;
int left[l1+1],right[l2+1];
for(int i=0;i<l1;i++)
{
    left[i]=a[p+i];
}
for(int j=0;j<l2;j++)
{
    right[i]=a[q+j];
}
left[l1+1]=INF;
right[l2+1]=INF;
i=0;
j=0;
for(int k=0;k<=r-p;k++)
{
    if(left[i]<right[j])
    {
        a[k]=left[i++];
    }
    else
    {
        a[k]=right[j++];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: i can't understand what does this mean...please help!

Comment: You need to debug it to find the actual error. If the program crashed, it will always give you an exception. That will tell you what's wrong specifically.

Comment: Quick note: Calculate mid by `mid = start + (end-start)/2' instead of `mid = (start+end)/2'. It will avoid integer overflow in case of very large data. It's **good programming practice.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tried to access an **out of bounds index** in the following lines (in `merge()` subroutine):

```
left[l1 + 1] = INF;
right[l2 + 1] = INF;
```

The size is `l1+1` and `l2+1` respectively. So, the range of valid indices will be `[0, l1]` and `[0, l2]`. The lines should thus be:

```
left[l1] = INF;
right[l2] = INF;
```

The final problem is in the line:

```
for(int k = 0; k <= r-p; k++)
```

which should be

```
for(int k = p; k <= r; k++)
```

otherwise, you will just overwrite the other values. You have to insert the merged part at the proper position.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir....yeah i found my error...as i was to remove this question from here i found you have already solved the problem...this is my first question on stackoverflow....i am amazed...thanks a lot!

Comment: @ShubhamChaudhary If you are satisfied with the answer then consider accepting it.

Comment: one more mistake i did is       for(int k = p; k <= r; k++) not      for(int k = p; k <= r-p; k++) but really thankful to you!